# I use "select2:opening" event with Ajax but select2 options do not fill in first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-select2

I use "select2:opening" event with Ajax but select2 options do not fill in first click. But it works second click on the select2 dropdown area. this is my code:

```
$("#Select2ID").on("select2-opening", function () {
            var e = document.getElementById("AnotherID");
            code= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/Controller/Action',
                    data: { "Code": code},
                    success: function (data) {
                        selectClear("Select2ID");
                        var select = document.getElementById("Select2ID");

                        for (var item in data) {
                            var opt = document.createElement("option");
                            opt.value = data[item].id;
                            opt.innerHTML = data[item].text;
                            select.appendChild(opt);
                        } //for end.

                    }, //success end.
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    },
                }); // ajax end.

            function selectClear(item) {
                var a = 0;
                var select = document.getElementById(item);
                while (select.firstChild) {
                    select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
                } //while end.

            }//selectTemizle end.

        });
```

Comment: check this post i think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705098/jquery-select2-prevent-selecting-in-ajax-response/26706695#26706695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `async:false` and I solved my problem.

```js
$.ajax(
    {
        async: false,    // <---
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
...
```